# cakephp how to reference string from file

Tags: cakephp

I need to create a file to contain all string in my website and I want to use Cakephp to reference strings in that file like string.h in android. Please help me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: [Internationalization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this for translation purposes you should get a look on cake localization support. You create the string files for languages on the 'locale' folder and use `__("string")` instead of `"string"` so cake will look for the translation of "string" in the folder correspondent to the current language.

[Doc in cakephp 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1230/Localization-in-CakePHP)

[Doc in cakephp 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

It is the closest of what you asked on cake, if that isn't what you have in mind you will probably have to write it from scratch,